# Ansible nested loop tries to iterate over "all", "ungrouped" values only

Tags: ansible

I try to create an Ansible role which adds four lines to two files. I want to add line A, B, C and D to files `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `login`.

I created a role:

```
---
  - name: Add a line
    lineinfile:
      path: "/etc/pam.d/{{ item.0.name }}"
      insertafter: #some line
      line: "{{ item.1 }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{ paths }}"
      - "{{ groups }}"
```

In `vars` folder I have a `main.yml` file with:

```
---
paths:
  - name: sshd
  - name: login

groups:
  - "line A"
  - "line B"
```

etc.

`paths` works fine, line was added to proper files but Ansible doesn't add `line A` and `line B`. In this files after Ansible I have line `all`, `ungrouped`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`groups` is a [magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts), you can't override it in your playbooks:

> `groups` is a list of all the groups (and hosts) in the inventory.

Rename your list to `mygroups` or something.